# Not like the rest - Moving everything within <script> tag to js file -Not working

Tags: javascript, external

Essentially, I've read all the posts that Stackoverflow say is related to my problem, but non seems to fix it. I'm trying to move everything within the script tags and i've linked the file but it's definitely not working

```
 < script type = "text/javascript" >

  var data = {
    countries: ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
      "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
      "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
      "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
      "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
      "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
      "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
      "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon",
      "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea",
      "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
      "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
      "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
      "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
      "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
      "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco",
      "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
      "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
      "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino",
      "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",
      "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain",
      "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan",
      "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
      "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
      "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
    ],
    capitals: ["Abu Dhabi", "Abuja", "Accra", "Adamstown", "Addis Ababa", "Algiers", "Alofi", "Amman", "Amsterdam",
      "Andorra la Vella", "Ankara", "Antananarivo", "Apia", "Ashgabat", "Asmara", "Astana", "Asunción", "Athens",
      "Avarua", "Baghdad", "Baku", "Bamako", "Bandar Seri Begawan", "Bangkok", "Bangui", "Banjul", "Basseterre",
      "Beijing", "Beirut", "Belgrade", "Belmopan", "Berlin", "Bern", "Bishkek", "Bissau", "Bogotá", "Brasília",
      "Bratislava", "Brazzaville", "Bridgetown", "Brussels", "Bucharest", "Budapest", "Buenos Aires", "Bujumbura",
      "Cairo", "Canberra", "Caracas", "Castries", "Cayenne", "Charlotte Amalie", "Chisinau", "Cockburn Town",
      "Conakry", "Copenhagen", "Dakar", "Damascus", "Dhaka", "Dili", "Djibouti", "Dodoma", "Doha", "Douglas",
      "Dublin", "Dushanbe", "Edinburgh of the Seven Seas", "El Aaiún", "Episkopi Cantonment", "Flying Fish Cove",
      "Freetown", "Funafuti", "Gaborone", "George Town", "Georgetown", "Georgetown", "Gibraltar", "King Edward Point",
      "Guatemala City", "Gustavia", "Hagåtña", "Hamilton", "Hanga Roa", "Hanoi", "Harare", "Hargeisa", "Havana",
      "Helsinki", "Honiara", "Islamabad", "Jakarta", "Jamestown", "Jerusalem", "Juba", "Kabul", "Kampala",
      "Kathmandu", "Khartoum", "Kiev", "Kigali", "Kingston", "Kingston", "Kingstown", "Kinshasa", "Kuala Lumpur",
      "Kuwait City", "Libreville", "Lilongwe", "Lima", "Lisbon", "Ljubljana", "Lomé", "London", "Luanda", "Lusaka",
      "Luxembourg", "Madrid", "Majuro", "Malabo", "Malé", "Managua", "Manama", "Manila", "Maputo", "Marigot",
      "Maseru", "Mata-Utu", "Mbabane Lobamba", "Melekeok Ngerulmud", "Mexico City", "Minsk", "Mogadishu", "Monaco",
      "Monrovia", "Montevideo", "Moroni", "Moscow", "Muscat", "Nairobi", "Nassau", "Naypyidaw", "N'Djamena",
      "New Delhi", "Niamey", "Nicosia", "Nicosia", "Nouakchott", "Nouméa", "Nukuʻalofa", "Nuuk", "Oranjestad",
      "Oslo", "Ottawa", "Ouagadougou", "Pago Pago", "Palikir", "Panama City", "Papeete", "Paramaribo", "Paris",
      "Philipsburg", "Phnom Penh", "Plymouth Brades Estate", "Podgorica Cetinje", "Port Louis", "Port Moresby",
      "Port Vila", "Port-au-Prince", "Port of Spain", "Porto-Novo Cotonou", "Prague", "Praia", "Cape Town",
      "Pristina", "Pyongyang", "Quito", "Rabat", "Reykjavík", "Riga", "Riyadh", "Road Town", "Rome", "Roseau",
      "Saipan", "San José", "San Juan", "San Marino", "San Salvador", "Sana'a", "Santiago", "Santo Domingo",
      "São Tomé", "Sarajevo", "Seoul", "Singapore", "Skopje", "Sofia", "Sri Jayawardenepura Kotte", "St. George's",
      "St. Helier", "St. John's", "St. Peter Port", "St. Pierre", "Stanley", "Stepanakert", "Stockholm", "Sucre",
      "Sukhumi", "Suva", "Taipei", "Tallinn", "Tarawa Atoll", "Tashkent", "Tbilisi", "Tegucigalpa", "Tehran",
      "Thimphu", "Tirana", "Tiraspol", "Tokyo", "Tórshavn", "Tripoli", "Tskhinvali", "Tunis", "Ulan Bator", "Vaduz",
      "Valletta", "The Valley", "Vatican City", "Victoria", "Vienna", "Vientiane", "Vilnius", "Warsaw",
      "Washington, D.C.", "Wellington", "West Island", "Willemstad", "Windhoek", "Yamoussoukro", "Yaoundé", "Yaren",
      "Yerevan", "Zagreb"
    ]
  };

$('#search').typeahead({
  minLength: 1,
  order: "asc",
  group: true,
  groupMaxItem: 6,
  hint: true,
  dropdownFilter: "All",
  template: "{{display}}, <small><em>{{group}}</em></small>",
  source: {
    country: {
      data: data.countries
    },
    capital: {
      data: data.capitals
    }
  },
  debug: true
});

 < /script>


<script src="/js/searchForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="submitTransfer">
  <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Phone Number">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Lead Name">
  <br>
  <div class="typeahead-container">
    <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Admissions Rep Name">
  </div>
  <button id="formsubmit">Send Data</button>
  <br>
  <textarea id="response" style="width: 230px; height: 100px; resize: none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `script` element to **below** the HTML it operates on. As it is, your code hooking up the click handler on the `search` element runs before the element exists, and so doesn't hook up anything.

Fails:

```
<script>
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    alert("Hi there");
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="foo">
```

Succeeds:

```
<input type="button" id="foo">
<script>
$("#foo").on("click", function() {
    alert("Hi there");
});
</script>
```

(And that's true for external script files as well.)

In general, unless you have a specific reason for doing something else, `script` tags go at the **end** of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. (For this reason.)

A second-best solution is to use jQuery's `ready` callback:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click", function() {
        alert("Hi there");
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="foo">
```

Comment: The above snippet is the external js file "searchForm.js" , and the snippet below is the HTML. How would that work, could you please just enlighten me a bit here. I'm learning this new language and just need a little bit more explanation as to do this with the external file present

Comment: @masterplox: Again: Move the `script` that includes the JavaScript to **below** the HTML. Put it right before the closing `</body>` tag.